# Excel VBA code to copy rows to relevant named sheets not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have found this code on this site from a previously answered question from two years ago.
The code looks at the rows of data on a Master Sheet and copies the relevant rows based on column D (Project) to the named sheet.

If a named sheet does not exist, a comment box is added to Column D, stating that the sheet name does not exist.

The code also looks at Column A (Invoice) and uses this a a unique ID so duplicate rows are not copied to the named sheets.

I amended the code to suit my needs (sheet titles, etc) but when I run the code, the relevant row is NOT copied to the named sheet but to the next sheet to the right.

I can't work out what is wrong with the code. Hoping someone can help!!!

```
Column A   Column B     Column C      Column D
Invoice    Date         Amount        Project
I18-1234   1/10/2018    $125.00       Project 1
I18-5678   10/10/2018   $1,500.00     Project 2
I18-2468   20/10/2018   $10,000.00    Project 1
I18-7931   15/10/2018   $300.00       Project 3
I18-1010   24/10/2018   $1,000.00     Project 1
```

I have a main sheet named "Master Sheet". This is where all data is entered.

Currently, I have another sheet named "Project 1".

The other sheets I have are named "Sheet2" and "Sheet3". (This is just while I test the code).

```
Sub Test()

Dim cell As Range
Dim cmt As Comment
Dim bolFound As Boolean
Dim sheetNames() As String
Dim lngItem As Long, lngLastRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet, shtMaster As Worksheet
Dim MatchRow As Variant

'Set master sheet
Set shtMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Data")

   'Get the names for all other sheets
ReDim sheetNames(0)
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name <> shtMaster.Name Then
        sheetNames(UBound(sheetNames)) = sht.Name
        ReDim Preserve sheetNames(UBound(sheetNames) + 1)
    End If
Next sht
ReDim Preserve sheetNames(UBound(sheetNames) - 1)

For Each cell In shtMaster.Range("D2:D" & shtMaster.Cells(shtMaster.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
bolFound = False

' instead of looping through the array of sheets >> use Application.Match
If Not IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value2, sheetNames, 0)) Then
    bolFound = True
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetNames(Application.Match(cell.Value2, sheetNames, 0)))

    ' now use a 2nd Match, to find matches in Unique column "A"
    MatchRow = Application.Match(cell.Offset(, -3).Value, sht.Range("A:A"), 0)
    If Not IsError(MatchRow) Then
        shtMaster.Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sht.Cells(MatchRow, 1)

    Else '<-- no match in sheet, add the record at the end
        On Error GoTo SetFirst
        lngLastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
        On Error GoTo 0
        shtMaster.Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sht.Cells(lngLastRow, 1)
    End If

End If

If bolFound = False Then
    For Each cmt In shtMaster.Comments
        If cmt.Parent.Address = cell.Address Then cmt.Delete
    Next cmt
    cell.AddComment "no sheet found for this row"
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
End If

Set sht = Nothing
Next
Exit Sub

SetFirst:
    lngLastRow = 1
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your part of the code :

```
' instead of looping through the array of sheets >> use Application.Match
If Not IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value2, sheetNames, 0)) Then
    bolFound = True
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetNames(Application.Match(cell.Value2, sheetNames, 0)))
```

to

```
' instead of looping through the array of sheets >> use Application.Match
If Not IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value2, sheetNames, 0)) Then
    bolFound = True
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cell.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Your code does copy the relevant data to the named sheet. The problem I found is if the data on the master sheet has been identified as having no named sheet and a comment flag is placed in column D, the next time your code runs with correctly named sheets, the comment flag also copies to the named sheet. Your code seems to skip the other part of my code where comments are deleted.  I also have a macro run button on the master sheet and that is being copied to the named sheet also.